# How to fancy slice numpy array and get a shallow copy?

Tags: numpy, numpy-slicing

Perhaps this has already been solved but I haven't found a neat answer. I am trying to slice a numpy array using an index array, and I want the sliced array to be a shallow copy of the original array.

I think that this can be solved creating an array of pointers, using ctypes but I feel that it is going to be cumbersome. I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do it (i.e., less code, numpy-based)

For example:

```
>>> x = np.arange(10)
>>> index_array = [1, 4, 6]
>>> y = x[index_array]
>>> print(sum(y))
11
>>> x += 1
>>> print(sum(y))
11
```

I am getting the same sum, since `y` is a copy of `x`, not a view. I'd like to define

```
>>> y = shallow(x, index_array)
```

such that the entries of y are references to the entries of x, and

```
>>> x += 1
>>> print(sum(y))
14
```

**EDIT**

Found useful information here:
[Views vs copies in Numpy](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html): There is no way to get a shallow copy of fancy slices as suggested in the comments, will write C code and wrap it to make it interoperable with the numpy array.

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I have a numpy array x whose values are variable, however, I need to do some calculations based on certain values of x, every time x changes. Broadcasting and copying the slice of x is inefficient for my application, therefore, I'd like to have something like an array of pointers to be more efficient.

Comment: Fancy indexing will always make a copy. You can try to create a new class derived from ndarray and play with __ getitem __ method.

Comment: And just assigning directly into the indexed array?

Comment: what do you mean @NilsWerner? extracting the references and saving them in the indexed array?

Comment: Well in that simple case you could've done `x[index_array] = 1`

Comment: @NilsWerner, the thing is that I don't want to change x, I modified the example to be more clear. Thanks for the valuable inputs.

Comment: Again, you're not explaining what you're trying to solve. You're just saying the solution you would like to have doesn't work :-)

Comment: `numpy` arrays are essentially object oriented wrappers around primitive, numeric C arrays. Saying a "shallow copy" doesn't make much sense in this context. What you are looking for is a *view*, which numpy only supports for simple slicing, not fancy indexing (which would be arduous to implement, but you are welcome to try). If you are going to use an array of pointers, then you might as well just use a regular Python `list` object, in which case, it will just work like you want it to.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga, just found that out.